# javascript event Handler in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am displaying one UIWebView in my iPhone application. In UIWebView I am displaying HTML page which has JavaScript also. I want to call method(of X Code) when one button is clicked in HTML page.

How can I do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 38):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to call an Objective C method from a javascript `onClick` event handler in your `UIWebView`.  The way to do that is to redirect the browser to a URL with a custom scheme in your javascript code like this:

```
function buttonClicked() {
    window.location.href = "yourapp://buttonClicked";
}
```

Back in Objective C, declare that your view controller conforms to the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol,

```
@interface DTWebViewController : DTViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
...
```

set your controller as the web view's delegate,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
}
```

and intercept the URL before it loads like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([[request.URL scheme] isEqual:@"yourapp"]) {
        if ([[request.URL host] isEqual:@"buttonClicked"]) {
            [self callYourMethodHere];
        }
        return NO; // Tells the webView not to load the URL
    }
    else {
        return YES; // Tells the webView to go ahead and load the URL
    }
}
```

Comment: cool, this also works for intercepting anchor clicks, the navigationType will be UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked

Comment: function buttonClicked() {
    window.location.href = "yourapp://buttonClicked";
}

can you tell more about these lines

Comment: This works great with the following change: yourapp://buttonClicked should contain a host component, like yourapp://www.yourapp.com/buttonClicked. Then the path will be "/buttonClicked". Otherwise, it will be an empty string.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on ios9, does anyone know why?

Comment: hi, I'm using your code with Swift, but nothing is happen, my code: unc webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest,navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType)-> Bool{ if (request.URL!.scheme == "index//clickFunction") { self.move() return false } else return true. Thought, request is equal "index//clickFunction", it runs to else return true. So, where I was wrong, please?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift Version**

```
webView.delegate = self

extension ViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if request.description == "yourappname://buttonClicked" {

            // do your stuff here
            return false
        }
        return true
    }    
}
```

**Example HTML**

```
<a href="yourappname://buttonClicked">
    <img src="http://someurl.com/table_desktop.jpg"/ width="100%">
</a>
```

If you want to know how to do it in `wkWebView`, here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574864/catch-javascript-event-in-ios-wkwebview-with-swift/34575373)

Comment: Its in swift. not objective c