# Get Notification when a video starts or stops in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

Hello i am new to objective - c

I'm having a problem with the `UIWebView` and `MPMoviePlayerController`: My `UIWebView` has a movie inside the html (it's a local html file), I'm using html5 and a video tag for the video.

I want a notification when video starts or stops in `UIWebView`....

I have tried using `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`, but it doesnt fire ...

I have also tried to make the my main `UIViewController`'s view a view of my own, and intercept `-didAddSubview:` and `-willRemoveSubview:`. but with no sucess...

Does any body know how to get notification from `uiwebview`??

Answer (score 19):

You can observe `@"MPAVControllerPlaybackStateChangedNotification"` (use `nil` for the object).  This notification isn't documented so I don't know if the App Store will approve your app.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(playbackStateDidChange:)
    name:@"MPAVControllerPlaybackStateChangedNotification"
    object:nil];
```

The notification has the key `MPAVControllerNewStateParameter` in its `userInfo`.  The value seems to be 0 before playback starts, 1 when it is paused, 2 when it is playing, and 3 (momentarily) when you are dragging the playback slider.

```
- (void)playbackStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSLog(@"note.name=%@ state=%d", note.name, [[note.userInfo objectForKey:@"MPAVControllerNewStateParameter"] intValue]);
}
```

Comment: awesome advice - i often told people that a web view movie player could not be observed for notifications - gee, guess I was wrong then.

Comment: It doesn't actually know which movie player it's observing.  Hopefully you only have one to observe.  :)

Comment: how to change the video from playing to paused, just from the notification?

Comment: Are there any alternate solutions like above?

Comment: @Susim   Did u find any alternative for this?

Comment: @JasmeetSingh no I remembered so far

Comment: @Susim In iOS 8 I found AVSystemController_NowPlayingAppIsPlayingDidChangeNotification which is another private notification. It has a AVSystemController_NowPlayingAppIsPlayingNotificationParameter which is 0 when stopped or 1 when playing.

Comment: This approach is working for me in iOS 8: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6869408/462162. Instead of calling a function when the user clicks a button as shown in that answer, you can call a function from the JavaScript onplay and onpause events.

Comment: @arlomedia Hi, could you please give more details about your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I searched alot about this..Here is the solution that I have found for getting the playback end notification call. **Tested code on iOS6.0 and above**. All thanks to **@Morten**.

In viewDidLoad add observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(playbackDidEnd:)
name:@"MPAVControllerItemPlaybackDidEndNotification"//@"MPAVControllerPlaybackStateChangedNotification"
object:nil];
```

Then simply add following javascript code `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate as below

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    //http://stackoverflow.com/a/12504918/860488
    [videoView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"\
                                    var intervalId = setInterval(function() { \
                                        var vph5 = document.getElementById(\"video-player\");\
                                        if (vph5) {\
                                            vph5.playVideo();\
                                            clearInterval(intervalId);\
                                        } \
                                    }, 100);"];
}

- (void)playbackDidEnd:(NSNotification *)note
{
//do your stuff here
    [videoView removeFromSuperview];
    videoView.delegate = nil;
    videoView = nil;
}
```

You will get playbackDid End call in the above selected and can do whatever is your requirement.
Happy Coding !!