# iOS 6 not playing Vimeo embedded videos

Tags: mobile-safari, ios6, vimeo

This is my first question. I've searched all over StackOverflow and Google for answers but have been unable to find one.

I have a video embedded on my website using Vimeo's universal iFrame code. The video can be seen below and will play just fine with any Desktop Browser and iOS 5 device.

**The problem comes with the latest update to iOS...**
Now on iOS 6, the video will not play. Instead it'll be stuck in a "loading" holding pattern. Using iOS 6 on iPhone Simulator for XCODE yields the same result. The link to the exact video in question is below. Loading on an older iOS 5 device and the video starts playing just fine.

Note: the video does NOT play on iOS 6 Chrome as well, however works in iOS 5 Chrome.

http://www.seriouslyfunny.tv/2011/03/padded-room-promo/

Any ideas? I feel this is a stupid newbie questions and someone's 8 year old nephew will know the answer.

Comment: It seems this is a Vimeo problem. You should contact Vimeo and ask them why your video does not play.

Comment: This question needs to be reopened and is not off-topic.

Comment: Michael, this is an issue with the way apple handles embedded videos. Unfortunately, I only have a solution that works on the devices themselves and do not know how you would implement it on your webpage. Nevertheless, here's something which I hope will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462052/youtube-video-playback-broken-on-ios6-works-fine-on-ios5

Comment: @nalply - You are correct, this was a vimeo problem. The solution was to download the original videos from Vimeo, then re-upload them to allow vimeo to re-process the videos.

Once the videos were re-uploaded, I used the embed code generated from those videos and they played perfectly. Not the best solution as it did seem the problem was on Vimeo's end, but it worked for our solution. 

Thank you to everyone to answered.