# How to launch youtube video in browser without tapping on the play icon

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, youtube

I am using the below code to play youtube url:

```
NSString *youtubeUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@",[photo videoUrl]];
[self embedYouTube:[youtubeUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] frame:CGRectMake(10, 120, 300, 200)];

- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSString* embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
        background-color: black;\
    color: black;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    if(videoView == nil) {
        videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        videoView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        [self.view addSubview:videoView];
        [videoView setHidden:NO];
    }
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```

User need's to tap on the webview to play this video. Can't it directly load the video without tapping on the play icon?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

add a parameter `autoplay=1` to the URL, like this:

```
NSString *youtubeUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@?autoplay=1",[photo videoUrl]];
```

Comment: Webview is unable to parse if I include '?' in the link so I have updated the link with slashes: http://www.youtube.com/v/%@/autoplay/1  ------ But it is not playing. how can I solve this issue?

Comment: can you `NSLog` the value of `youtubeUrl` after adding `?autoplay=1` an post the result?

Comment: In browser it is playing properly, if I give this link http://www.youtube.com/v/_6wiHPxa-_U?autoplay=1 ----- When I test the app in iPhone it is not opening the video. it still requires tap on the play button.

Comment: Here is the html string:<html><head>    <style type="text/css">    body {        background-color: black;    color: black;    }    </style>    </head><body style="margin:0">    <embed id="yt" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/_6wiHPxa-_U?autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"     width="300" height="200"></embed>    </body></html>

Comment: are you using iOS6?, I read that Apple change the way the youtube's videos are handled and autoplay didn't work, try the other answer or check the answers in this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462052/youtube-video-playback-broken-on-ios6-works-fine-on-ios5)

Comment: in that case you has to simulate the touch on the play button, you can try with the answer given by @TonyThomas or look for others options in the link I give you in my previous comment

Comment: Yeah I am trying both the solutions. Thanx for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this way to embed your play, which support Auto PLay

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: I do not think this is allowed within the scope of the question (i.e. mobile Safari).

Answer (score 0):

You should check [LBYouTubePlayerController](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView) which uses the MoviePlayer component to load youtube videos and it's a lot easier to customize things, like autoplay feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is, if you're displaying videos with a webView autoPlay is no longer allowed per Apple guidelines. The [docs specifically state](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH2-SW8):

> Warning: To prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at
>   the user’s expense, embedded media cannot be played automatically in
>   Safari on iOS—the user always initiates playback.

This same doc is referenced from Google Developer / [YouTube API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations).