# iOS: UIWebView <input> text handle changed events

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, webkit

I have an `UIWebView` fill form. I want to catch the input events the same way as for `UITextFieldDelegate` or `UITextViewDelegate`.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can try doing it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869199/javascript-event-handler-in-uiwebview

Comment: It's not really like what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible, because elements(textfields and others) on uiwebview form are not cocoa touch objects. So,they can transmit events to your application through its responder chain.

U can make validation,using javascript,but it's not application's bussiness.This should be done on server side,which provides u this form.

Comment: Too bad:( Generating HTML generated forms would make life easier:( This case I will need to generate these forms by using UITableViewCells:( Lot's of woork.