# Javascript return a string to objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

i got a webview and i would like to capture an input from a webview HTML form. i have tried but i cant can some one help me please

this is my webview code

```
        // Init Web View
    UIWebView *webView;
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:boundsRect];
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    webView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
    [self addSubview:webView];
    [webView release];
    return self;
```

To get value from webView, i used below code.

```
NSString* value = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('text').value"]‌​; 
NSLog(@"got: %@",value);
```

Comment: i have tried with this :  NSString* value = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('text').value"];
       
        NSLog(@"got: %@",value);

Comment: And the problem is ? `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` return nil ?

Comment: yes i doen't return any thing

Comment: it return an empty string `@""` or nil ?? not 'anything' ...

Comment: empty string [2925:707] got:
this is from the log console

Comment: is there a way to only execute that con afeter an HTML buton is pressed?

Comment: So the script success, simply that your input `value` property is empty.

Comment: To execute it after an HTML button is pressed see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869199/javascript-event-handler-in-uiwebview

Comment: but value is comming from the result of the script

Comment: i tryed and i couldn't do it is it that complicated to send a value from javascript to xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into how phonegap http://phonegap.com/ solves this.