# WKWebView get Javascript Errors

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

Is there any way to get the JavaScript errors from the WebView? I mean the following errors and possible warnings?

[image: JS error]

I am running JS code with the following extension:

```
extension WKWebView {
    func evaluateJavaScriptWithReturn(_ javaScriptString: String) -> String? {
        var finished = false
        var jsValue: String?
        
        evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptString) { (result, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if result != nil {
                    jsValue = result as? String
                }
            } else {
                jsValue = nil
            }
            finished = true
        }
        
        while !finished {
            RunLoop.current.run(mode: .defaultRunLoopMode, before: Date.distantFuture)
        }
        
        return jsValue
    }
}
```

But `error` is not what I'm looking for!
Is there any way to get in my app, the above errors?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you please share URL? So we can also debug it

Comment: @iMHitesh its localhost, and i have produced the error by myself so i can get it on xcode print for example :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To handle errors, we are going to add some JavaScript to the HTML we load into our page that will notify our native code about the error.

First, you need to setup your web view with a script message handler:

```swift
let controller = WKUserContentController()
controller.add(self, name: "error")

let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.userContentController = controller

let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
```

I locally create the full HTML document and inject the following JavaScript:

```js
window.onerror = (msg, url, line, column, error) => {
  const message = {
    message: msg,
    url: url,
    line: line,
    column: column,
    error: JSON.stringify(error)
  }

  if (window.webkit) {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.error.postMessage(message);
  } else {
    console.log("Error:", message);
  }
};
```

(I have the check and log since I sometime run the generated JavaScript in a browser.) You could also use the `WKUserContentController` to add a `WKUserScript` if you want to inject it into HTML you don’t fully control.

Next when you load a string into your web view, **be sure to use `localhost` as the base URL**. If you don’t do this, all of your errors will be `"Script error."`.

```swift
webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: URL(string: "http://localhost/")!)
```

Now define your `WKScriptMessageHandler`:

```swift
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    switch message.name {
    case "error":
        // You should actually handle the error :)
        let error = (message.body as? [String: Any])?["message"] as? String ?? "unknown"
        assertionFailure("JavaScript error: \(error)")
    default:
        assertionFailure("Received invalid message: \(message.name)")
    }
}
```

You can add other cases to the switch statement for other messages you add to the `WKUserContentController`.

Comment: Going to accept this certain answer as a correct one.
I've already been handling error messages in this certain way! 
And mosdef I should also update my question with the way I did it. Thaks Sam!

Comment: Worked for me on iOS (12, 13) to get JS errors in the Xcode log.  I had to use "http://localhost/" as stated in the solution.  Also, use `WKWebView` `initWithFrame:configuration:`  Plus 1.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the significance of localhost? I see how base url is important for relative url resolution in the page, but how is it related to errors turning "Script error"?

Comment: If you don't use `localhost` as the host in `baseURL` all errors will just be `"Script error."` instead of the real error message.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following way.

**First**, inject JS code to catch the error in html content:

```
window.onerror = function(error) {
  alert(error); // Fire when errors occur. Just a test, not always do this.
};
```

**Second**, display the error in WKWebView delegate method:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "alert", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("An error from web view: \(message)")
}
```

Remember to set delegate:

```
webView.uiDelegate = self
```

If you want to avoid the alerts, the alternative way is using `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` method to receive the JS's callback which is like `window.open("error://message","_self")`

Comment: Now I think using `webkit.messageHandlers` is a better solution.Details are in  @3spot 's answer and this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574864/catch-javascript-event-in-ios-wkwebview-with-swift

Answer (score 7):

In the JavaScript, hook the window onerror event to call back your script message handler:

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.mylog.postMessage("JS: ERROR:" + msg + " @" + url + ":" + line);
};
```

You may just get "Script error." messages, which is a permissions issue. ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)) Depending on your setup this can be fixed by adding a permission to your preferences. 
Swift:

```
webView.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
```

Comment: `allowFileAccessFromFileURLs` is a private property

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found is to use Safari's Web Inspector.  There are instructions found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html).

I kept running into `Script error.` messages with Yun CHEN's solution (which was great) with no actionable content.

Comment: You need to make sure your base URL is `localhost` to fix `"Script error."` see my answer for more details.